# How to create an Excel VBA script by Using Automation from Visual C#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I wanna create an Excel VBA script to refresh data from database, so I have written this code:

```
xlModule = xlWorkBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
xlModule.Name = "Module3";

String macroCode = "' Makro 1\r\n" +
                "Sub odswiezCykleZBazyLineCycle()\r\n" +
                "   Application.StatusBar = \"Refreshing sheet Cycle_from_DB\" \r\n" +
                "   ActiveWorkbook.Connections(\"Connection\").refresh \r\n" +
                "   Application.StatusBar = \"\" \r\n" +
                "End Sub";
xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(macroCode);
```

But after executing this code, I don't see any VBA scripts in my Excel file. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways fo doing this that I have used which are more fully described [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

Here's how to add code to a module.

```
Dim CodePan As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim S As String
Set CodePan = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule
S = _
"Sub ABC()" & vbNewLine & _
"    MsgBox ""Hello World"",vbOkOnly" & vbNewLine & _
"End Sub" & vbNewLine
With CodePan
    .InsertLines .CountOfLines + 1, S
End With
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, still I don't see in my excel file any modules and any macros. I haven't any ideas to solve this problem. Is it enough to create module:
`VBIDE.VBProject VBProj = xlWorkBook.VBProject;
            VBIDE.VBComponent VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
            VBIDE.CodeModule CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule;
            VBComp.Name = "NewModule";`

Comment: @Robert did you check out the help available in the link.  It guides you through creating such code.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. But if I add in code this line:
`xlApp.Run(odswiezCykleZBazyLineCycle);`
then macro will execute once (while app is executting), but still I don't see this macro on the list of macros in excel file.

Comment: I discovered that before using method `xlApp.close()` macro exists in excel file, but after `close()` it disappears.

Comment: There is no close on the code you posted. Are you saving the file before closing it? Silly question?